# Modelling a room from a reference image

Tags: modeling

I need to model and render a scene from a reference image, which is an image of a corner of a room with some objects in it. I've modelled some of the objects and am now trying to model the room itself with walls, a ceiling and a floor. Is there a good method of lining up the walls, ceiling and floor relative to each other and setting the camera to the correct point according to the reference image or is eyeballing it the way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Use fSpy. It’s designed specially for what your dealing with.
https://fspy.io/

Comment: And to understand all its options (including the principal point, determining focal length etc) I would highly recommend my Complete fSpy tutorial released yesterday ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daiMOYR8GS8